# Why can't I change the aspect ratio of my project in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, aspect

I am trying to create a Final Cut project that has a 4:3 aspect ratio. So I went to the project settings and set it to 1440x1080. But the preview window and exported video is still widescreen, does anyone know why?

[image]

Does that squiggly line have anything to do with it?

Just so you can see, my project is set to the right resolution, but the preview window is clearly playing a widescreen video:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

When you import clips the default spatial conform is fit. Change it to fill and clips will be cropped. You can reframe as you like.

This article has more details [Square video with FCPX](https://www.fcp.co/final-cut-pro/tutorials/1941-how-to-edit-publish-square-video-with-final-cut-pro-x)